# how to get incogonito model using chromedriver in karate

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, karate

I know that I can pass addOptions for example for native chrome:
addOptions: [ '--incognito' ]

however, the addOption only works for the native chrome not with chromedriver,
I tried to pass in this as a

- def session = { capabilities: { browserName: 'chrome' }, desiredCapabilities: { addOptions: '--incognito' } }

but I don't think it is getting picked up as well when I pass this session in.

I have to use incogonito as chrome will otherwise log my LDAP in when I am my company VPN. I want my test program under a service account.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on whether whatever driver executable you are calling supports that option or not, Karate just passes it.

You are welcome to do some research and contribute your findings (and ideally code) to this open-source / community.